# Enable swagger-ui in matlab REST API

Tags: docker, matlab, rest, microservices, swagger-ui

I am trying to build a docker image which when launched as a container, it will expose a REST API with two endpoints: `/statistics` (POST method with function name and parameters) and `/api/health` (GET method which returns 200 status `ok`). To do that, I use the following matlab commands:

```
mservice = compiler.build.productionServerArchive('Addition.m', 'ArchiveName', 'statistics', 'Verbose', 'on')

compiler.package.microserviceDockerImage(mservice, 'imageName', 'myImage')
```

Then I run the image as the following:

```
docker run -p 5002:9910 myImage -l trace
```

Everything works fine and I am able to send requests to both my endpoints successfully. However, now I want to enable `swagger-ui` to my rest api so that I will have something similar to Flask in Python: `http://localhost:5002/swagger-ui`. I am not sure how to do that, can somebody help? thanks.